# WCF Service Fails to Decode UTF-8 from Mobile Client

Tags: c#, wcf, utf-8

I have a WCF service which needs to support UTF-8 encoded queries.  An example of the interface definition looks like this:

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetLocationID")]
    List<GetLocationIdResult> GetLocationID(Stream locationIDparams);
```

The endpoint definition uses webHttpBinding, as follows:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="External" name="Customer.Customer">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Customer.ICustomer"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

When I send queries with words in Hebrew from a .NET based web client or Fiddler, the query parameters read correctly. Sent from a mobile client (Android or iOS), parameters are not properly decoded, but shown as question marks.

It is very easy to say that the client is misconfigured, but I need to solve the problem, not cast blame.  Is there something in my configuration that I can do to resolve the issue?  I don't have a debug server that the client can address, queries must go to the customer's server, where I can debug by writing to the event manager (anyone remember printf?).  What can I look  for using such tools to help correct the client's configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to activate WCF tracing and message logging as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526%28v=vs.110%29.aspx